# ggplot2 displays incorrect bars (every 12th bar is at minimum value)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to make bar charts with ggplot2 with the following dataset.

```
Incentive Marginal.Abatement.Cost    Tech
1  Status Quo                    -100  Tech 1
2  Status Quo                     -99  Tech 2
3  Status Quo                     -98  Tech 3
4  Status Quo                     -97  Tech 4
5  Status Quo                     -96  Tech 5
6  Status Quo                     -95  Tech 6
7  Status Quo                     -94  Tech 7
8  Status Quo                     -93  Tech 8
9  Status Quo                     -92  Tech 9
10 Status Quo                     -91 Tech 10
11 Status Quo                     -90 Tech 11
12 Status Quo                     -89 Tech 12
13 Status Quo                     -88 Tech 13
14 Status Quo                     -87 Tech 14
15 Status Quo                     -85 Tech 15
16 Status Quo                     -83 Tech 16
17 Status Quo                     -81 Tech 17
18 Status Quo                     -79 Tech 18
19 Status Quo                     -77 Tech 19
20 Status Quo                     -75 Tech 20
21 Status Quo                     -73 Tech 21
```

The dataset goes on like that for 91 observations. When I plot it using the below ggplot code, every 12th bar for some reasons shows -100 regardless of what it should be.

```
ggplot(CRIFQuo, aes(x = Tech, y = Marginal.Abatement.Cost)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm going to assume that your Tech column is a factor. It's probably not ordered the way you expect. Try `Tech <- factor(Tech, levels=uniq(Tech))` to re-order in the order they appear in the data.frame. Otherwise they are sorting lexicographically (ie `sort(c("Tech 1", "Tech 2", "Tech 11"))`).

Comment: @MrFlick judging by x axis, ggplot2 tries hard to represent all categories. If it were numeric, it would probably try to find pretty breaks.

Comment: That was dumb of me @MrFlick. Thank you!

Comment: if my answer solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark ...

Answer (score 3):

As identified by the commenters, R sorts factor levels alphabetically by default, e.g.

```
sort(paste0("x",1:12))
## [1] "x1"  "x10" "x11" "x12" "x2"  "x3"  "x4"  "x5"  ...
```

On the other hand,

```
gtools::mixedsort(paste0("x",1:12))
## [1] "x1"  "x2"  "x3"  "x4"  "x5"  "x6"  "x7"  ...
```

You can reorder your factor levels as follows

```
CRIFQuo$x <- with(CRIFQuo,factor(x,levels=gtools::mixedsort(levels(x)))
```

before re-trying your plot (you'll need to install the `gtools` package first, of course)

Alternatively, you could turn your x variable into a numeric:

```
CRIFQuo$nTech <- as.numeric(gsub("^Tech ","",CRIFQuo$Tech)
ggplot(CRIFQuo, aes(x = nTech, y = Marginal.Abatement.Cost)) ...
```